# Email is not CC'd when a membership on behalf of organisation contribution is made

Tags: civicontribute, civimember

When an individual joins on behalf of an organisation, the receipt/invoice is not CC'd to the individual. It goes to the organisation email.

On the email, it says it is CC'd to the individual but it does not arrive.

Any ideas? I'm basically trying to email the individual who completed the contribution page, not the organisation.

Comment: can you please add CiviCRM version in your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this with CiviRules. You can create a rule saying that when a new membership is added send an e-mail to a related persion.

You need both CiviRules and the email api extensions.